# Stripe API is extremely slow for listing invoices

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments, stripe-connect

I am building Stripe SaaS , that retrieves all invoices for registered users and do some statistics

My server on Godaddy shared server with 512mb ram , the page load time may take 20 seconds which is too bad for performance this is if user has 50 invoice

I am using Laravel 5.4 framework with Stripe package

this is my code in Controller

```
    \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey($secret_key);

    $invoices=  \Stripe\Invoice::all(array("limit" => 100));
```

and my view is

```
 @foreach($invoices->autoPagingIterator() as $invoice)
                                <tr>

                                <td>invoice.created</td>
                                    <td> {{$invoice->id}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$invoice->amount_due}}</td>
                                    <td> {{$invoice->attempt_count}}</td>
                                    <td> {{$invoice->livemode}}</td>
                                    <td> {{$invoice->charge}}</td>
                                    <td> {{$invoice->currency}}</td>
                                    <td> {{$invoice->customer}}</td>
                                    <td> {{$invoice->date}}</td>
                                    <td> {{$invoice->description}}</td>
                                    <td> {{$invoice->discount}}</td>
                                    <td> {{$invoice->ending_balance}}</td>
                                    <td> {{$invoice->period_end}}</td>
                                    <td> {{$invoice->period_start}}</td>
                                    <td> {{$invoice->subscription}}</td>
                                    <td> {{$invoice->paid}}</td>


                                </tr>
                                @endforeach
```

the logic is the secret key is stored in database and every user has his own key
I want to know that is the best practice to do the SaaS without heavy loading

Comment: As with @Rick I've done similar. Instead of doing any polling against Stripe, I just mirrored their data model and stored everything locally. The Rate Limiting can become really problematic as your application grows.

Comment: Hi @petter-adam if this or any answer below solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this but it's generally good practice to do so.

Answer (score 5):

Stripe has built in rate limiting to prevent you lifting too much data at once.

We recently built a system for our clients (We use Stripe Connect so act as a 'middleman' between customers and businesses, taking a fee) that needed a way of us showing previous invoices. The only real way we came up with was to sync the data and keep a local copy.

This took a week to run through all our old data, but now runs on the fly with queueable events handling pulling stripe data as it gets created.

My advice would be to set up a queue to pull all invoice data down to your own db, where you can then format and display without that noticeable loading lag. Combine that with query caching and indexing and you should have a pretty fast setup with low server overhead.

As a sidenote I would also recommend looking into a better hosting option than shared hosting as you'll have a lot of issues trying to do things like queues and schedules with such a limited environment. A simple DigitalOcean or Linode box coupled with Laravel Forge makes Laravel specific deployment and management a lot easier in the long run.